# Query triangle in which a point lies in CGAL 2D

Tags: cgal

I am working with 2D meshes with all triangles, represented using CGAL as `CGAL::Surface_mesh<K::Point_2>`. Given a set of 2D points, I want to find in which triangle each points is.

I have tried `CGAL::AABB_tree`, but apparently the `CGAL::AABB_traits` is made for 3D queries. I guess I could use 3D meshes with `z = 0`, but in that case I fear the AABB may be incorrect, since the bounding boxes will have 0 length in the z direction.

Which would be the best way to perform this 2D lookup?

Comment: The simplest solution is indeed to put z=0 as there is no 2D AABB-tree for now.

Comment: @sloriot Does one still achieve logarithmic complexity for point lookup if the bounding boxes are all zero thickness?

Comment: It should not be a problem, the z direction will never be picked for a split

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Location Functions](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon_mesh_processing/group__PMP__locate__grp.html).
Did you consider using a 2D triangulation and a projection traits as an alternative? See this [example](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_2/index.html#title15).

Comment: I read about triangulations, and It looks like it might work, but it says something about the convex hull and I was wondering if it only supports convex triangulations. I have no experience with them so, still a bit scared of using them